# Making Upload button for shapefile in QGIS plugin?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqgis-3, qt-designer, pycharm

I am new to Plugin Builder and creating my first plugin called `NearestNeighbour`. The below is GUI of my plugin made using `Qt Creator`

[image]

I read in this [link](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/building_a_python_plugin.html) that it is important to rename Dialog Box, Toolbox because it  will be used in our code.
`Label` are kept as it is with object name `label` and `label_2` respectively. The `LineEdit`  objectName for Upload Node Layer is called `lineEdit`. On a similar basis the second `LineEdit`  objectName for Upload Building Layer is called `lineEdit_2`. In a similar way the `Push Button`for Upload Node Layer is called `pushButton` and the second `Tool Button` for Upload Building Layer is called `pushButton_2`. With reference to the link mentioned above, I have done the Following change in my `Nearest_Neighbou.py`

1) Add the below line where all imports are done

```
 from qgis.core import QgsProject
```

2) Add `QFileDialog` to `QtWidget` to the list of imports at the top of the file.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction, QFileDialog
```

3) Add a new method called Upload_Point_Layer with the following code just above `def(run)self:`

```
def Upload_Point_Layer(self):
  filename, _filter = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(
  self.dlg, "Select   output file ","", '*.shp')
  self.dlg.lineEdit.setText(filename)
```

4) In the run method, added the following line in the block where the dialog is initialized.(This code will connect the Upload_Point_Layer method to the clicked signal of the push button widget)

```
 self.dlg.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Upload_Point_Layer)
```

I want to know what I am doing wrong or are there any other files that also need to be edited ? I am using `QGIS3.6` on `32 Bit Windows` operating System and using `Pycharm` as `Python IDE`

But after saving the changes, when I tried to reload the plugin I have got the below error

```
Couldn't load plugin 'Nearest_Neighbour' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method 

AttributeError: 'NearestNeighbour' object has no attribute 'dlg' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 335, in startPlugin
plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
File "C:/Users/Prachi/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\Nearest_Neighbour\__init__.py", line 36, in classFactory
return NearestNeighbour(iface)
File "C:/Users/Prachi/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\Nearest_Neighbour\Nearest_Neighbour.py", line 73, in __init__
self.dlg.lineEdit.clear()
AttributeError: 'NearestNeighbour' object has no attribute 'dlg'
```

Comment: `QFileDialog.getSaveFileName` is not correct, and where is `self.dlg.lineEdit.clear()` ?

Comment: why `QFileDialog.getSaveFileName` is  not correct. It now works for me. till now I haven't added `clear()` `thing ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at step 23 in the [tutorial](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/building_a_python_plugin.html) you'll see 
some lines in the `run` method:

```
if self.first_start == True:
   self.first_start = False
   self.dlg = SaveAttributeDialog()
```

You need to find those lines and make sure they are called before you try to use the dialog anywhere. Also check that the name matches the name of your dialog (probably something like `NearestNeighbourDialog`).

Comment: Yes I think there was a identation error but it works now . Thank you :) I have written some processing for local use and it works very well in qgis python. It need to just copy and paste code  in `pass` section of `def(run)self:` method right ?